# 各列の値を持つセルの値を取得したい

Tags: google-apps-script

引数arrayが0以外の場合意図する動作が実現できないようです。誰か問題点を指摘できますか ?

```
const spreadsheets = [];
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("X");
spreadsheets.push(spreadsheet);

function problem(array,index){
  const things =[];
  const sheets = spreadsheets[0].getSheets();
  const values =sheets[index].getRange(1,array+1,1000,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
//problem(0,1):[[a1],[a2],[],[],[],[],.....]
//problem(1,1):[[b1],[b2],[b3],[],[],[],.....]
  for(let i=0;i<1000;i=i+1){
    if(values[i][array]==""){break;}
    things.push(values[i][array]);
    }
  Logger.log(things);
//problem(0,1):[a1,a2]
//problem(1,1):[null,null,null,......]
  return things;
}
```

| spreadsheets[0].getSheets()[1] | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a1 | b1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 |
| 3 |  | b3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

二次元配列へのアクセスが誤っているのが原因です。

```js
  Logger.log(values);
//problem(0,1):[[a1],[a2],[],[],[],[],.....]
//problem(1,1):[[b1],[b2],[b3],[],[],[],.....]
```

`values` には、「「1つだけ要素のある配列（＝セル、より正確には1行から幅が1つ分）」の配列（ ＝`getValues()` で取得した範囲）」が入っています。

なので、例えば `a1` の部分を取得するには `values[0][0]` 、 `a2` の部分を取得するには `values[0][1]` 、同様に `problem(1, 1)` で `b1` の部分を取得するには `values[0][0]` 、……とアクセスする必要があります。

というところで続きのコードですが、

```js
  for(let i=0;i<1000;i=i+1){
    if(values[i][array]==""){break;}
    things.push(values[i][array]);
    }
  Logger.log(things);
//problem(0,1):[a1,a2]
//problem(1,1):[null,null,null,......]
```

…… `values[i][array]` というアクセスをしています。これは、

- `problem(0, 1)` の時：`values[0][1]`（a1） 、`values[1][1]` （a2）にアクセスする
- `problem(1, 1)` の時：`values[1][1]` （ `null`） 、`values[1][1]` （ `null`）、……にアクセスする
  （無限に `null` がかえるので、終了しない）

という結果を起こします。
ですので、 `values` へのアクセス方法を修正すれば解決するでしょう。